# How do I select an element inside a variable in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that takes an accordion element (I have multiple accordions in one page) and passes it into another function. In the second function I'd like to select the first header inside each accordion. How do I do this?

```
$(document).ready( function()
 {

$(".accordion").each(function(){
    prep_accordion(this);
});

 });
```

I tried this. The first statement in this function selects all elements, the second one only selects one element, but works only the first time. I want it to select the first header in every accordion

```
function prep_accordion( element )
 {
     var headers = $(element).find('.accordion-header'); //Selects all headers
     var header = $('.accordion-header').first();  //Selects first header, but only the first time function is called.

}
```

Comment: `header` should probably be `headers.first();`

Comment: i mean... your code does exactlu what you've coded it to do. You're calling prep_according on every .accordion element, and for each one, you're finding the header within it and potentially doing something. I don't see a problem. The second line though isn't a good idea.

Comment: @KevinB As I've pointed out, I believe that's the intention - however that is *not* what his code is doing. His `header` variable is set to the first occurrence of `.accordion-header` regardless of relationship.

Comment: @Santi No, he's finding every header within the element, for each. So, yes, it eventually finds them all, but not because `element` isn't what he wants it to be.

Comment: `var header` does not reference the element parameter - it's an independent selector that will select the same element on the page every single time, regardless of how the function is called, or what parameter is passed.

Comment: The comments on both of your lines are innacurate. The first selects all headers *within $(element)*, and the second selects the first header on the page, every time. It works on every iteration, but every iteration is affecting the first header on the page. You want a combination of the two lines.

Comment: @Santi `headers.first()` did not work. Only selects the recent pass of the function, since I have two accordions, it selects the header for the second one

Comment: Are you even doing anything with the variables you're setting though? What does the rest of your function do?

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?

Comment: @Santi Yes, the function goes on to do some expand-collapse stuff

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down a bit...

Here, you use `$(element).find()`, so that your search is restricted to only the accordion headers within the current element:

```
var headers = $(element).find('.accordion-header'); //Gets the current accordion's headers
```

---

But here, you make *no reference to the `element` parameter*.  This will select the first header *on the page* because you haven't limited your selection to only the current element:

```
var header = $('.accordion-header').first(); //Gets the first accordion-header on the entire page
```

---

Being that you already have a list of the headers for the current element, there's no need to user another selector. Just grab the first header from the list you already have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".accordion").each(function(){
        prep_accordion(this);
    });

});

function prep_accordion(element) {
    var headers = $(element).find('.accordion-header'); //Selects all headers
    var header = headers.first(); //Gets the first header for the given element
}
```

Comment: This did not work. Only selects the recent pass of the function, since I have two accordions, it selects the header for the second one

Comment: The code I've provided above will select the header for each accordion as it loops through them. If you're still experiencing an issue, it's likely somewhere in the code that you've omitted. If you want more help, you'll need to include the rest of your code in the question.